# Insert dropdown menu, text fields and checkbox in Paypal "add to cart" button

Tags: javascript, button, paypal

This is my first post so please be patient.

I'm trying to setup an "add to cart" button which is able to host information provided by customers via a dropdown menu, some text fields and some checkboxes. So that once the customer select one entry from the dropdown menu, inserts the info in the text fields and marks the checkboxes, the seller is able to receive all the info together. I have already been able to include the dropdown menu and the text fields.

I'm not able to do the following things:

- setup checkboxes
- find a way to make sure that for each line (such as lines 1 and 2 in the below photo), only one checkbox is selected (no multiple selections)
- find a way to display a warning message if all information are not provided. This means that if a customer does not select the item type (which is "shirt" in the photo below) from the dropdown menu (the first entry is a fixed "select item") or leaves blank any text field or checkbox, a warning message like "provide all the info please" is displayed.

I'm not looking forward to use php or others so my question would be, how do I do that using html and JavaScript?

I attach here an image of what I am looking for. In the image there are just 4 text fields and 6 checkboxes (3 per line) but the text fields will be more. The lines dedicated to checkboxes should be 3 to 5. Each line will have 3 checkboxes as shown in the picture:

[image]

Here is the code so far (makes no use of JavaScript)

```html
<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" target="self">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="http://www.example.com">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="user@email.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Customization for item">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="8.00">
<table><tr><td>
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Item type">Item type</td>
    <td>
    <select name="os0">
    <option value="select item">SELECT ITEM
    <option value="Shirt">Shirt
    </select></td>
</tr></table>
<br>

First Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="First Name">
<input type="text" name="os0" size="20">
<br><br>
Last Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Last Name">
<input type="text" name="os1" size="20">
<br><br>
Favorite color:&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Favorite color">
<input type="text" name="os2" size="20">
<br><br>
Favorite pet:&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="hidden" name="on3" value="Favorite pet">
<input type="text" name="os3" size="20">
<br><br>
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and 

secure!">
</form>
```

Comment: Radio buttons are basically mutually exclusive checkboxes. That would meet your 'only 1 checkbox checked' requirement

Comment: _“find a way to display a warning message if all information are not provided”_ - go read up on the basics of HTML5 form validation, most of that stuff can be handled without much extra programming on the client side. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation (Whether you might still need to do server-side validation, depends on your specific use case.)